# Can file copying be CPU-bound?

Tags: linux, io, linux-kernel, operating-system, kernel

As far as I know, the CPU is usually faster than an I/O device (like the HDD, the network, RAM, etc.), so when copying a file the bottleneck is usually I/O-bound (right?).

If under some condition that I/O device is faster than the CPU (like in a virtual machine) is it possible to keep the CPU busy moving data (like from buffer to kernel space, from kernel space to user space)? And does it then become CPU-bound?

Comment: IO devices can never be faster than the CPU, unless they have their own CPU, either way they still have to be issued a command from the CPU. Also when copying a file the CPU just issues the command to the IO device, it doesn't do the copying. Also the VM is going to be stored on an IO device and loaded in to RAM, and RAM will never be faster than CPU.

Comment: Normally I/O is not CPU intensive because the data transfer is performed by an I/O processor (e.g. a DMA controller).  If you want the file copy to be CPU bound, then perform the transfer using PIO, programmed input/output.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It depends on the program and the conditions where the program is run.
It would be highly unlikely that the speed of a program copying data would be throttled by the CPU speed. However it could be the case if for example the computer runs other programs that use CPU intensively and with higher priority than the program executing the copy.

The most common bottleneck would be the persistence storage medium speed (e.g. Hard drive).
Then, the amount of RAM available.
Then, the CPU being unavailable.

If and only if however, an I/O device is so super fast that outperforms the CPU speed. Then, it could be the case. However this is a hypothetical case since the CPU does not usually performs the copy itself, but commands other hardware to do so. 
And, in real systems the bandwidth available for I/O device are far slower than the CPU and RAM bandwidth.

If copy is done efficiently, copying RAM data to HDD should not stress the CPU. 
Data from RAM and Northbridge can be copied to the HDD via the Southbridge. 
See also [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Northbridge_%28computing%29).

If copy is done inefficiently, of course a program could read every single byte with the CPU and copy it.

Furthermore, as one can infer, the answer also depends from the hardware and architecture of the system.

Comment: so when writing some date from ram to disk,(ex:1GB data), will those 1GB data be processed by CPU?

Comment: the question above is relative to the thing you mentioned "the CPU does not usually ... hardware to do so.",thank you.

Comment: or just one CPU command to let other hardware do the 1GB copy job?

Comment: I updated my answer, normally this can be handled by Northbridge/Southbridge chipsets and the OS. However nothing prevents a program from actively copying byte by byte everything.

Answer (score -1):

Wrong answer, I am afraid.  At least not always correct.

If I copy a folder with some 50.000 files (different sizes) in Windows Explorer, then TaskManager reports that the copy is mostly CPU bound. (I.e. TM reports low disk usage and very high CPU usage)

Comment: I have tried the way you did above. yes, for 50,000 files case, I saw high CPU rate on Task Manager. but after I just copied a large file(said 10GB), TM does report high disk usage instead of high CPU rate.

Comment: Exactly my experience too.  
For instance, if I do a DB backup of a large DB, then Task Manager reports that the process is bound by disk, not CPU.